# Salesforce - Conga Merge Template Excel

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I want to use an excel template for report purpose on Salesforce and i use conga Composer.
I need to add some photos coming from salesforce on that excel template. I am able to to do that easily on Word.
What is the IMAGE prefixe Excel Conga Template?

In word It is: `{{IMAGE:FieldName}}`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to open the Conga Template Builder to get it.

https://documentation.conga.com/composer/latest/create-a-template-with-template-builder-158341702.html

Basically, you take the URL found in one of the buttons. Go to an Opportunity or whichever object you whitelisted for Conga Composer. Go to the URL of that.

[image]

```
https://[org].lightning.force.com//apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?id={!Opportunity.Id}
```

and load that in your web browser. Top right is a drop down, hit the template builder.

[image]

Then there is an option at the bottom that says "Word" and "Excel". It'll change the formats.

[image]

[image]

There is also this documentation: https://documentation.conga.com/composer/latest/excel-templates-184424153.html

If you're using Conga Queries or whatnot, you just run those in the browser minus all the background params and settings. For example:

```
https://[org].lightning.force.com//apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?id={!Opportunity.Id}&QueryId=[test]a078a000018v7cRAAQ
```

As far as images based on your original question, not seeing anything obvious. Have you tried contacting support?